# Fallback function requires too much gas

Tags: solidity, contract-development, gas

This is my contract and logic inside fallback function is not so complicated, but why does it tell that my fallback function requires too much gas? How do I fix this problem?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

contract owned {
    address public owner;

    function owned() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner public {
        owner = newOwner;
    }
}

interface tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData) public; }

contract MyCoin {
    // Public variables of the token
    string public name = "MyCoin";
    string public symbol = "XYZ";
    uint8 public decimals = 18;
    // 18 decimals is the strongly suggested default, avoid changing it
    uint256 public totalSupply;
    uint256 initialSupply = 50000000;

    // This creates an array with all balances
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

    // This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    // This notifies clients about the amount burnt
    event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);

    /**
     * Constrctor function
     *
     * Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract
     */
    function MyCoin() public {
        totalSupply = initialSupply * 10 ** uint256(decimals);  // Update total supply with the decimal amount
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;                // Give the creator all initial tokens
        //name = tokenName;                                   // Set the name for display purposes
        //symbol = tokenSymbol;                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
    }

    /**
     * Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract
     */
    function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
        // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
        require(_to != 0x0);
        // Check if the sender has enough
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
        // Check for overflows
        require(balanceOf[_to] + _value > balanceOf[_to]);
        // Save this for an assertion in the future
        uint previousBalances = balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to];
        // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        // Add the same to the recipient
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        // Asserts are used to use static analysis to find bugs in your code. They should never fail
        assert(balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to] == previousBalances);
    }

    /**
     * Transfer tokens
     *
     * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` from your account
     *
     * @param _to The address of the recipient
     * @param _value the amount to send
     */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public {
        _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    }

    /**
     * Transfer tokens from other address
     *
     * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` in behalf of `_from`
     *
     * @param _from The address of the sender
     * @param _to The address of the recipient
     * @param _value the amount to send
     */
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);     // Check allowance
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Set allowance for other address
     *
     * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens in your behalf
     *
     * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
     * @param _value the max amount they can spend
     */
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public
        returns (bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Set allowance for other address and notify
     *
     * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens in your behalf, and then ping the contract about it
     *
     * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
     * @param _value the max amount they can spend
     * @param _extraData some extra information to send to the approved contract
     */
    function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData)
        public
        returns (bool success) {
        tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
        if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
            spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData);
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Destroy tokens
     *
     * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly
     *
     * @param _value the amount of money to burn
     */
    function burn(uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);   // Check if the sender has enough
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;            // Subtract from the sender
        totalSupply -= _value;                      // Updates totalSupply
        Burn(msg.sender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Destroy tokens from other account
     *
     * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly on behalf of `_from`.
     *
     * @param _from the address of the sender
     * @param _value the amount of money to burn
     */
    function burnFrom(address _from, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);                // Check if the targeted balance is enough
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);    // Check allowance
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                         // Subtract from the targeted balance
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;             // Subtract from the sender's allowance
        totalSupply -= _value;                              // Update totalSupply
        Burn(_from, _value);
        return true;
    }
}

/******************************************/
/*       ADVANCED TOKEN STARTS HERE       */
/******************************************/

contract MyAdvancedToken is owned, MyCoin {

    uint256 public sellPrice = 500;
    uint256 public buyPrice = 500;
    uint256 private endTime = 123456; //@TODO

    mapping (address => bool) public frozenAccount;

    /* This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients */
    event FrozenFunds(address target, bool frozen);

    /* Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract */
    function MyAdvancedToken() MyCoin() public {}

    /* Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract */
    function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
        require (_to != 0x0);                               // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
        require (balanceOf[_from] > _value);                // Check if the sender has enough
        require (balanceOf[_to] + _value > balanceOf[_to]); // Check for overflows
        require(!frozenAccount[_from]);                     // Check if sender is frozen
        require(!frozenAccount[_to]);                       // Check if recipient is frozen
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                         // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                           // Add the same to the recipient
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    }

    /// @notice Create `mintedAmount` tokens and send it to `target`
    /// @param target Address to receive the tokens
    /// @param mintedAmount the amount of tokens it will receive
    function mintToken(address target, uint256 mintedAmount) onlyOwner public {
        balanceOf[target] += mintedAmount;
        totalSupply += mintedAmount;
        Transfer(0, this, mintedAmount);
        Transfer(this, target, mintedAmount);
    }

    /// @notice `freeze? Prevent | Allow` `target` from sending & receiving tokens
    /// @param target Address to be frozen
    /// @param freeze either to freeze it or not
    function freezeAccount(address target, bool freeze) onlyOwner public {
        frozenAccount[target] = freeze;
        FrozenFunds(target, freeze);
    }

    /// @notice Allow users to buy tokens for `newBuyPrice` eth and sell tokens for `newSellPrice` eth
    /// @param newSellPrice Price the users can sell to the contract
    /// @param newBuyPrice Price users can buy from the contract
    function setPrices(uint256 newSellPrice, uint256 newBuyPrice) onlyOwner public {
        sellPrice = newSellPrice;
        buyPrice = newBuyPrice;
    }

    /// @notice Buy tokens from contract by sending ether
    function () payable public {

        //this is minimum what you can buy
        require(msg.value >= 1 / buyPrice);

        //ICO has to be active
        require(now < endTime);

        //get amount of tokens to send to the seller
        uint amount = calculateAmount(msg.value);
        uint bonus = getBonus(amount);

        //Xmas or NewYear give them 50% more tokens
        //uint bonus = ;

        _transfer(this, msg.sender,  amount + bonus);
    }

    /**
     * Get bonus for Xmas and New Year
     */
    function getBonus(uint _amount) constant private returns (uint256) {
        if(now >= 5000 && now <= 5001 || now >= 6000 && now <= 6001) { //@TODO pripremi vrijeme, dodaj jos koji random dan za popuste
            return _amount * 50 / 100;
        }  

        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * Calculate how mush XYZ you need to send
     */
    function calculateAmount(uint _amount) constant private returns (uint256) {
        //phase 1 (10 days)
        if(now >= 1000 && now <= 20000) { //@TODO
            // calculates the amount
            return _amount * buyPrice + (buyPrice * 50 / 100);
        } 
        //phase 2 (15 days)
        else if (now >= 1000 && now <= 20000) { //@TODO
            return _amount * buyPrice;
        } 
        //phase 3 (20 days)
        else {
            return _amount * buyPrice - (buyPrice * 50 / 100);
        }
    }

    /// @notice Sell `amount` tokens to contract
    /// @param amount amount of tokens to be sold
    function sell(uint256 amount) public {
        require(this.balance >= amount * sellPrice);      // checks if the contract has enough ether to buy
        _transfer(msg.sender, this, amount);              // makes the transfers
        msg.sender.transfer(amount * sellPrice);          // sends ether to the seller. It's important to do this last to avoid recursion attacks
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fallback function performs token transfer, and token transfer modifies token holder balances in contract's storage.  Any storage modification costs more than 2300 gas, and fallback function, when called with no data, is supposed to fit into 2300 gas.
If fallback function does not fit into 2300 gas when called with no data, then ether cannot be sent to your contract from other contracts via `send` or `transfer` functions.  Though, ether may still be sent to your contract from plain (non-contract) Ethereum accounts, and ether may still be sent to your contract from other contracts via `call` or `selfdestruct` functions.  Many crowdsale contracts have fallback functions that do not fit into 2300 gas.

P.S. Most multisig wallets use `call` function to send ether, so it will be possible to send ether from multisig wallets to your contract even if fallback function in your contract does not fit into 2300 gas.

Answer (score 2):

As per official doc ([here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html?highlight=fallback#fallback-function)) , fallback function can have access to only 2300 gas if it's called with `send()` . In that case, there is no way to specify an amount of gas to forward to you fallback function (It's just enough to send ether and then do a basic log operation).

You can however call the same fallback function with `call()` and then specify an amount of gas to be forwarded . ([here](https://github.com/ConsenSys/Ethereum-Development-Best-Practices/wiki/Fallback-functions-and-the-fundamental-limitations-of-using-send()-in-Ethereum-&-Solidity) a nice link speaking about that)

Comment: I read the documentation before. It doesn't really help me. I don't understand why is this happening with my callback function

Answer (score 2):

Your `endTime` in your advance token is set to `uint256 private endTime = 123456; //@TODO`. When your `fallback` function gets called it verifies `require(now < endTime);` since it's false it will not work.

You should try setting an actual value and test it again. I know that in Mist if your contract will fail, it warns you and the gas price will be really high.

EDIT

Okay so the problem is that when you're creating your coin your giving the owner all the initial supply and then when receiving ether you try to send tokens from the contract but the contract does not own any token. You can change it to give the initial tokens to the contract

```
function MyCoin() public {
    totalSupply = initialSupply * 10 ** uint256(decimals);  // Update total supply with the decimal amount
    balanceOf[this] = totalSupply;                // Give the creator all initial tokens
    //name = tokenName;                                   // Set the name for display purposes
    //symbol = tokenSymbol;                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
}
```

Comment: The same thing happens even when I set proper timestamp in the future. It says: http://prntscr.com/hlpacl  The problem is obviously in the logic of fallback function. I don't know how can I fix it

Comment: @FosAvance There's also time errors in your `getBonus` function

Comment: Does that explains why gas is so high? Because I fixed it and it's still the same

Comment: @FosAvance It seems to get stuck in your transfer function when it checks the balance of the sender

Comment: @FosAvance Check my edit

Comment: Is it even possible to have so much logic in that function?

Comment: @FosAvance Ya it's fine you can add a name to the function to get rid of the warning and then simply call that function. It works for me when I fix the balance of the contract like I said in my edit.

Comment: could you please post that part of the code?

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesn't solve the problem. Gas is still too high